# I'm tring to adding js_class to calendar view, but get the error below

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I can add other attributes like "string" etc, and it's worked.
But "js_class" cannot add like this.
My code:

```
    <record id="view_calendar_event_calendar" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">view.calendar.event.calendar.inherit.calendar_extend</field>
        <field name="model">calendar.event</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="calendar.view_calendar_event_calendar"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//calendar" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="js_class">calendar_extend_view</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Here is error:

```
  File "/home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo-source/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 360, in _check_xml
    raise ValidationError(_('Invalid view %s definition in %s') % (view.name, view.arch_fs))
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Invalid view view.calendar.event.calendar.inherit.calendar_extend definition in calendar_extend/views/calendar_event_views.xml
None" while parsing /home/odoo/odoo-dev/vpc-addons/calendar_extend/views/calendar_event_views.xml:89, near
<record id="test_view_calendar_event_calendar" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">view.calendar.event.calendar.inherit.calendar_extend</field>
        <field name="model">calendar.event</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="calendar.view_calendar_event_calendar"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//calendar" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="js_class">calendar_extend_view</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
> /home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo-source/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py(360)_check_xml()
-> raise ValidationError(_('Invalid view %s definition in %s') % (view.name, view.arch_fs))
(Pdb)
```

I'm sure about my js code is correctly.

Comment: I tried your view (the record tag) and it worked fine, in 12.0 and 13.0, your problem seems to be somewhere else!

Comment: Thanks for your time, i found this is a bug form src-code, and it has been fixed in Odoo12 CE. 
My odoo code is outdate.
Here is the link: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/31679

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone meet this problem, it might be your source code is outdated.
This problem has been fixed in OdooCE.
Here is the related issue in Github: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/31679

Answer (score 0):

Try Using **class** in place of **js_class** if you want to add the class attribute.

Pass your custom class and existing class like this. You can find out what the existing class is by using something like firebug or just "view source".
Just add a space, no comma between classes.

For Example:

```
<xpath expr="//calendar" position="attributes">
     <attribute name="class">existing_class custom_class</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Comment: Do appreciate your help, but the attribute name is not a problem (js_class or class).
Actually it's an original bug from odoo src-code.
Fortunately, I found the answer in github. 
If someone need it, here is the link:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/31679